# Efficient Computation of the expression

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, generating-functions, computational-complexity

I have been working on a problem for quite some time now and looking for a better approach.

> **Problem** : 
> You are given two integers $K$ and $N$.
>  For each **m** ($1 \le m \le N)$, you have to find the answer of the below expression
>
> $$X=\sum_{i=1}^K i^m$$
> Since answer can be large we have to return $X$ modulo $10^9+7$ for each **m**.
>
> **Constrainsts**: 
>  $1 \le K \lt 10^9+7 $ 
>  $1 \le N \le 10^5$

1. An obvious solution to the problem is a brute force approach of complexity $O(N*K)$.
2. A slightly better approach is the use of
   [Faulhaber's forumula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) which would reduce the complexity to $O(N^2)$ but still is quite slower.

I am looking for a better solution. So is there a way to compute Faulhaber's formula faster or is there a different approach for the above problem?

Any sort of help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

*If you look for approximations*.

Using generalized harmonic numbers$$X=\sum_{i=1}^k i^m=H_k^{(-m)}$$ If $k$ is large, you can use the asymptotics
$$\frac{H_k^{(-m)}-\zeta(-m)}{k^m}=\frac{k}{m+1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{m}{12 k}-\frac{(m-2) (m-1) m}{720
   k^3}+\frac{(m-4) (m-3) (m-2) (m-1) m}{30240
   k^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^7}\right)$$